# Unable to Hide Columns during Initial Load Using Freemarker condition

Tags: json, datatables, freemarker

I need to show default columns in DataTable which is populated using JQuery. I have a condition that if the json data evaluates to `initiallyHidden`, the columns which have the json data assigned should be hidden. I have tried the following things, but it didn't work:

```
<#list caseMgrConfiguration.columns as column>
    <#if column?counter <= 11>
       {
        data: "${column.label}",
        <#if column.Userselectable?? && column.Userselectable.intiallyHidden??>
              style="display:none"                                       
        </#if> 

       render: function (data, type, row) {
        return "<a href='/platform/${registry}/facility${facilityId}/case-report-form?patient_id=" + row.patientId + "&record_id=" + row.recordId + "'>" + data + "</a>";
        }
       },
    </#if>
```

What I exactly want is to show or hide css based on json value `initiallyHidden` which is coming from casemgr.json file. It is not throwing error, but it is not hiding column as well. Can someone guide me as to how do I do this?

Comment: You want the `a` tag be hidden?

Comment: Yeah, Ideally along with the column header the data also for that has to be hidden.so, yes. But i have put the if tag only for column headers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `foo??` tests if `foo` exists (non-`null`), not if it's `true` or `false`. So even if `foo` is `false`, `foo??` will be `true`. If you have reason to believe that the variable (`foo`) is missing (but otherwise it's a boolean), and in that case you want to treat is as `false`, then write `foo!false`. If you know it always exists, then just write `foo` (as in `<#if foo>`), no need for additional operators.

Comment: hi ddekany,thanks for the solution. also just wanted to know the line below if which is style="display:none" correct and would work?

Comment: I don't think so... it looks like a piece of HTML, but there's no tag around it. (Of course, FreeMarker doesn't care about that, it just prints what you tell it to print.)